# Estimate on a specific differential form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on a PDE problem and encounter a problem in one of the middle step. I have a differential form as: $\int_\Omega u\Delta v-v\Delta u$ over a bounded domain with smooth boundary. May I ask that are there any related results or reference that I can look into to estimate this term? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Green's second identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities) might help:
$$\int_\Omega \left(u \Delta v - v \Delta u \right) dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} \left(u \frac{\partial v}{\partial n} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \right) dS$$
for $u,v$ smooth functions over a bounded domain $\Omega$ with smooth boundary, and with $n$ being the outwards facing unit normal.